# Training and validation loss do not change with increasing number of epochs. Have tried changing batch size and learning rate

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, training-data

I am new to deep learning and python and am looking at performing a simple binary classification of cracked vs uncracked concrete using a small data set (1000 positive images (cracked) and 1000 negative images(uncracked)) and a pretrained VGG model. See below code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.utils.data as data
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.utils.data import Subset
 
#Pull in Image data

num_epochs = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 32
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
TRAIN_DATA_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Images3/Training'
VAL_DATA_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Images3/Validation'
TEST_DATA_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Images3/Testing'
TRANSFORM_IMG = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(256),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225] )
    ])

#Define train, validation, and test datasets

train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TRAIN_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
train_data_loader = data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True,  num_workers=4)

val_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=VAL_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
val_data_loader = data.DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

test_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TEST_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
test_data_loader  = data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Number of train samples: ", len(train_data))
    #print("Number of val samples: ", len(val_data)))
    print("Number of test samples: ", len(test_data))
    print("Detected Classes are: ", train_data.class_to_idx)

#Define VGG

def vgg_block(num_convs, in_channels, out_channels):
    layers = []
    for _ in range(num_convs):
        layers.append(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1))
        layers.append(nn.ReLU())
        in_channels = out_channels
    layers.append(nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

conv_arch = ((1, 64), (1, 128), (2, 256), (2, 512), (2, 512))

def vgg(conv_arch):
    conv_blks = []
    in_channels = 3
    # The convolutional part
    for (num_convs, out_channels) in conv_arch:
        conv_blks.append(vgg_block(num_convs, in_channels, out_channels))
        in_channels = out_channels

    return nn.Sequential(
        *conv_blks, nn.Flatten(),
        # The fully-connected part
        nn.Linear(32768, 4096), nn.ReLU(), nn.Dropout(0.5),
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096), nn.ReLU(), nn.Dropout(0.5),
        nn.Linear(4096, 2))

net = vgg(conv_arch)

#Train

num_epochs = 15
min_val_loss=np.inf
criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range (num_epochs):
  train_loss=0.0
  net.train()
  for data, labels in train_data_loader:
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    target=net(data)

    loss = criterion(target, labels)
    loss.backward #Backward pass, calculate gradients
    optimizer.step()
    train_loss += loss.item()

  val_loss=0.0
  net.eval()
  for data, labels in val_data_loader:
    target=net(data)
    loss=criterion(target, labels)
    val_loss = loss.item() * data.size(0)
  
  print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} \t\t Training Loss: {train_loss/len(train_data_loader)} \t\t Validation Loss: {val_loss/len(val_data_loader)}')
  print('Finished Training')
```

After training, I am getting train and validation loss values of ~0.693 that do not change with number of epochs. I have also tried pretrained networks NIN, DenseNet and ResNet, but all get similar unchanging values with increased number of epochs. I would greatly appreciate any help...

Comment: `loss.backward` is a function, so you need to use `loss.backward()` to actually call it, and compute gradients.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice that. I will fix and re-train. Thanks again